# Eclipse started crashing

Tags: eclipse, crash, stack-overflow, eclipse-pdt, eclipse-3.6

I have been using eclipse for a couple of weeks now, and all of a sudden it has started crashing with this error:

```
An internal error occurred during: "Selection Job titile".
java.lang.StackOverflowError
```

Here's some other info:

- It's the most recent build of Eclipse
  Helios
- I have installed subclipse
- I use mylyn a bit
- My current project is in SVN.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

**EDIT:** It is now crashing with all sorts of errors, different every time

Thanks,

Lemiant

Comment: Try at a command prompt:    ./eclipse -clean

Comment: Will that cause me to lose my tasks?

Comment: & do I use that exact command, or put the actual location of the eclipse folder

Comment: Run that command from you Eclipse directory ( unless it's in your path ).  And no, you wont lose anything, but your next start up of Eclipse will take a bit longer.

Comment: I ran it, and it said that . is not a recognized command, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Running windows. ;)   Loose the ./, just run eclipse -clean

Comment: When I do that it says that eclipse is not a valid command, but I went into the eclipse folder, and ran it on eclipse.exe and seems to be working.

Comment: Yes, that is what you are doing, you are running eclipse, just passing in the parameter -clean.  If you don't crash anymore after, its because your workspace got corrupted.

Comment: Thanks. I think that fixed it. Thanks for the taking the time to help.

Comment: I just had that problem with eclipse juno. Don't they fix bugs there? They had more than two years...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just throwing this up so that I can mark it as answered. Like Reapth said:

Command Prompt:

```
C:\Program Files\Eclipse\eclipse\eclipse.exe -clean
```

and its fixed.

Lemiant

Answer (score 0):

add maximum heap size, such as -Xmx348m
add perm size, such as -XX:MaxPermSize=256m